# Python - Multiple XOR Operations, NameError Not Defined

Tags: python

Disclaimer: I am a Python newbie, so I apologize if this code isn't pythonic or if there is a simpler/better way to write this. Any [constructive] criticism would be greatly appreciated!

Hey all, so I'm trying to create a script that will ask the user for a binary input up to 8 digits (will create actual asking for input once this works) and perform exclusive OR (XOR) operations on them and assign a Boolean value to a variable. Problem is, I can't figure out why I'm getting a name error. The code below involves three-input XOR gates.

Here's the error:

> if bool(G1) ^ bool(e) ^ bool(G2) :
>
> NameError: name 'G1' is not defined

From what I can tell, G1 isn't getting assigned anything.

```
a = 0
b = 1
c = 1
d = 0
e = 1
f = 1
g = 0
h = 1

#G1
if bool(b) ^ bool(c) ^ bool(d) :
    G1 = True
elif bool(b) ^ bool(c) == False :
    if bool(d) :
        G1 = True
elif bool(b) ^ bool(c) :
    if bool(d) == False :
        G1 = True
elif bool(b) :
    if bool(c) ^ bool(d) == False:
        G1 = True
else :
    G1 = False

#G2
if bool(f) ^ bool(g) ^ bool(h) :
    G2 = True
elif bool(f) ^ bool(g) == False :
    if bool(h) :
        G2 = True
elif bool(f) ^ bool(g) :
    if bool(h) == False :
        G2 = True
elif bool(f) :
    if bool(g) ^ bool(h) == False:
        G2 = True
else : 
    G2 = False

#G3
if bool(G1) ^ bool(e) ^ bool(G2) :
    G3 = True
elif bool(G1) ^ bool(e) == False :
    if bool(d) :
        G3 = True
elif bool(G1) ^ bool(e) :
    if bool(G2) == False :
        G3 = True
elif bool(G1) :
    if bool(e) ^ bool(G2) == False:
        G3 = True
else :
    G3 = False
```

Comment: You have quite a few paths where the variable isn't defined. Look at the second level conditions... what happens if they are not true?

Comment: @tdelaney - That was it! I was too focused on the higher-level conditions.

Comment: You need to initialize G1, G2, and G3 before you enter the if-statement, else they won't persist outside of their respective conditionals

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have constructs like

```
elif x ^ y: 
    if z:
        G1 = ...
else:
    G1 = ...
```

in your code. Even though one of the `elif` statements might be true in your case, the sub-condition where you check `z` is not. That means that `G1` is never actually assigned a value and therefore you get the undefined error.

To solve this problem, you could add an `else` clause to each of the sub-conditions for example. By doing so, you would ensure that `G1` will definitely be assigned.

So for example:

```
elif x ^ y: 
    if z:
        G1 = ...
    else:
        G1 = ...
else:
    G1 = ...
```

Comment: or, even better, initialize `G1` to `false` before the `if` statement

Comment: Sure, that would also work. But I wanted to point out where the error occurs, as it is a typical error which happens in lots of cases. Sometimes, if the value is not bool, you might want to assign a different value to the variable.

Comment: yes, but your proposed solution is unsafe; it requires that the conditional is always constructed in such a way as to cover every case, a condition that could easily be broken as requirements change. Initializing the variable to some default value and then conditionally changing it is much safer, and can work regardless of whether your values are booleans or not

Answer (score 0):

This is a common (and sometimes difficult to find) error. If you assign a variable inside a conditional that you want to use later, you either have to predefine a default for the variable before the conditional or make sure that every path in the conditional assigns the variable.

In your case its easy to spot the problem. For instance

```
elif bool(b) ^ bool(c) == False :
    if bool(d) :
        G1 = True
```

...what happens if that inner `if` isn't true? The variable is not assigned and you have a bug just waiting to nip you at the most inconvenient time.

Ideally a program should have companion tests that drive it through every possible state to make sure they all work. At a minimum, the code should be inspected manually expressly to find possible faulty exectution paths.